# Output related to promise resolution

Tags: javascript, promise

```
function somePromise () {
    return new Promise (resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve (3)
        }, 3000)
    })
}
async function solve() {
    console.log(1) 
    let data = await somePromise(); 
    console.log(2) 
    console.log(data)
}
solve();
```

The output for this code is:

> 1
> 2
> 3

My question is why is the value of data 3 and not the promise with state as fulfilled ?

I expected data to have a Promise and not the number 3.

Comment: *"I expected data to have a Promise and not the number 3."* - Remove the `await` keyword and observe.

Comment: `let x = await prom(); console.log(x)` is syntax sugar for `prom().then(x => { console.log(x) })`

Answer (score 2):

The point of using the [`await` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in an expression is to have that expression evaluate as *the resolved value of a promise* instead of as *the promise itself*.